# How to prevent 'grub rescue' from ever happening?

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, grub

I already know how to recover from 'grub rescue' and I'm not asking about it.

I barely have one HDD and I change its partitions for multiple purpose. But everytime I do so, I got 'grub rescue', I can handle but it is annoying. Is there any way to prevent `grub rescue` ? (e.g. replace grub with another loader, install my own script, etc.)

**UPDATE:** Add a few more details

- I don't use a partition as `/boot` but only `/`
- My root partition is a part of a bigger extended partition
- My root partition is not `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/sda5`. I use dual-boot (Windows is in `/dev/sda1`)
- I guess when I change a part of extended partition, its address/name (i.e. `(hd0,msdosX)`, I don't know what this is) changes, so avoiding 'grub rescue' while still use grub is perhaps impossible. May be change boot loader is the only solution
- In 'grub rescue', I saw that grub know how many partition and whether a partition is ext2/3/4 or not (by `ls` and `ls (hdX,msdosY)`), so if I could let grub scan for partition and boot the first found ext partition, problem solved!

Comment: What do you mean by "change its partitions"? Why do you have to do that? Touching the partitions is not something you should do on a daily basis.

Comment: @JohanMyréen remove/format/merge/split/clone partitions. I don't do it quite often, but it's still annoying (not just in 'grub rescue', but after that, I have to `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sda`)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the reason why grub is going into rescue mode.

It might be happening because grub is having trouble finding early-load parts of itself. For traditional PC partition tables, these parts are usually installed in a pseudo-safe spot in between the partition table the the first partition. In this case, don't disturb that area by installing a different boot loader or completely erasing the disk and reconstructing its partitions. For GPT partitions, these parts are installed in a dedicated BIOS boot partition. In this case, don't disturb/move that partition.

Or it might be happening because grub is having trouble finding late-load parts of itself or modules or its config. These are located on the `/boot` filesystem, if you have one, else on the root filesystem.

- If you use a `/boot` partition, don't disturb or move that partition and you should be safe.
- If you don't use a `/boot` partition and you find yourself playing with the root filesystem's partition in ways that disturb grub's ability to find it, consider using a `/boot` partition (which will be small and which you never touch) that grub will be able to find more reliably.

Comment: I don't use a `/boot` partition but use only `/` as root, however, my root partition (`/`) is not `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/sda5`. Unfortunately, it is a part of an *extended partition* - which is where "I change its partition for multiple purpose"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvoted, but since I cannot avoid disturbing extended partition, that's a nonsolution. Anyway, I updated my question (thanks to your details), do you have any other solution?

Comment: @DMaster I'm a little surprised that you find yourself having to shuffle partitions around all that much: for me I guess I'd usually install a machine once and then forget it... Anyway, my suggestion stands: use a `/boot` partition in a fixed location that you never touch. While you're at it, use LVM for all the rest of your partitions: it's easier to resize/change/shuffle/delete/add/manage with LVM without having to worry about low-level partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Once you boot into kali open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```